# Likelihood estimators for inhomogeneousPoission process

Tags: poisson-process, maximum-likelihood

Assume, i have an inhomogeneous Poisson process $N(t)$ with time-dependent intensity $\lambda$, i.e.

- $ N(0) = 0$
- $ N(t)-N(s) \sim \operatorname{Poiss}(\Lambda(s,t))$
- $N$ has independent increments.

where 
$$\Lambda(s,t) = \int_s^t \lambda(\tau) d \tau.$$

Now assume $\lambda$ is of known to be of form $\lambda(\tau)=f(\tau, \boldsymbol\beta)$, for a known function $f$ and unknown vector $\boldsymbol \beta$.

I have a sample of realizations of $N$ given in an interval $[0,T_{\max}]$: ($N(t,\omega_1), \ldots, N(t,\omega_n))$.

Now here is my question: If I want to get a maximum likelihood estimator for $\boldsymbol \beta$, I can chose a set $\{t_0,\ldots,t_k\}$ with $0=t_0 < t_1 < \ldots t_k=T$ and maximize the likelihood

$$\boldsymbol \beta = \arg\max_{\boldsymbol \beta} \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \prod_{j=1}^n \mathbb P\big(N(t_i)-N(t_{i+1}) = N(t_i, \omega_j) - N(t_{i+1}, \omega_j) \big).$$

So now I am a bit confused by the following questions:

- How does the partition of the interval $[0,T]$ affect my estimation of $\boldsymbol \beta$. Both the number of $t_j$ and also how do I distribute them on the interval?
- Is that a stupid question to ask, because I forgot something trivial?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: I am confused by your notation $N(t,\omega_1)$. By definition $N$ is a function of one input. What are the $\omega_1$, and how does one define $N(t,\omega_1)$?

Comment: hi, thanks for the question. $N(t,\omega_1)$ is just a trajectory of the Poisson process for a fixed $\omega_1 in \Omega$